# Error: Book is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPageCount in Citable. Should I make a class abstract due to interface class?

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, comparable

I'm trying to do a school project in which I'm writing an application that deals with books, collections of books (we’ll call that a library), and the UI client for those classes.

One of the classes is a class called Citable that requires the implementation of typical accessor features that return a book’s ISBN, Author, Title, and Publisher (all strings) as well as the Publication Year, Month, and Day (all integers) and a Page Count (an integer).

The next class a Book class that implements the Citable interface. Library will need to sort books by their ISBN numbers, so in Book you’ll need to provide support for that as well (hint: this requires the implementation of an additional interface (one you don’t have to write, just implement) and the writing of an additional method (which should only need one line of code), and that Library make a simple call to make the sort happen). There are no statics here (except for the test method), and no UI whatsoever. I'll show you what I've did so far:

```
public interface Citable
{
    public String getISBN();
    public String getAuthor();
    public String getTitle();
    public String getPublisher();
    public int getPublicationYear();
    public int getMonth();
    public int getDay();
    public int getPageCount();
}
```

and the book interface:

```
import java.util.*;
public abstract class Book implements Citable, Comparable
{
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Book
     */
    public Book()
    {
        Collections.sort(ISBN);
    }

    public String toString (){
        String info =  ISBN + "\n" + title + "\n" + author + "\n" + publisher + 
        "\n" + publicationYear + "\n" + month + "\n" + day;
        return info;
    }
}
```

In the Book class, I'm implementing both the interface I've made and Java's built-in Comparable. My question is this: In the Book class, I was getting the error: Book is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPageCount in Citable. The only way I could stop the error was to make the Book class abstract. However, I'm getting no indication that I should make that class abstract. Is there a way out of this?

Comment: Don't make your `Book` class abstract. Simply implement the methods from the `Citable` interface.

Comment: In your explanation, you interchange interface and class as if they mean the same thing. But they don't. Please take a time to read what you wrote and be more clear about what you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Book` implements two interfaces, namely `Citable` and `Comparable`. That means you have to implement the methods from these interfaces in your class. The only other way would be to make the class Book abstract, meaning you can't instantiate it. But that is definitely not what you want.

Your class `Book` would look something like this:

```
public class Book implements Citable, Comparable
{
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Book
     */
    public Book()
    {
        Collections.sort(ISBN);
    }

    public String toString (){
        String info =  ISBN + "\n" + title + "\n" + author + "\n" + publisher + 
        "\n" + publicationYear + "\n" + month + "\n" + day;
        return info;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        //Implement this method
    }

    @Override
    public String getISBN() {
        return isbn;
    }

    //other methods from your interfaces here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood from your solution strategy is creating an interface for the method contract and implementing this interface in your class.
In order to that firstly let me remind that, once you implement an interface you need to implement all of its abstract methods. The error is related with it. Thus, there are two options, First, you can implement Citable methods in Book class. Second, you can write these methods as default in Citable interface and just use them on Book class.
I have shared a sample code with some comments please check them

Sample Code:

```
import java.util.Collections;

public  class Book implements Citable, Comparable
{
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Book
     */
    public Book()
    {
        Collections.sort(getISBN());//there is no sort method for Strings, sort method is only for lists
    }

    public String toString (){
        String info =  getISBN() + "\n" + title + "\n" + author + "\n" + publisher + 
        "\n" + publicationYear + "\n" + month + "\n" + day;//You need to use getter methods
        return info;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getISBN() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthor() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPublisher() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPublicationYear() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMonth() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getDay() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPageCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try to implement the methods, but I'm still getting